# How to create website from XML documentation comments?

Tags: c#, .net, documentation

I would like to create a documentation website from C# [XML documentation comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

An example from the Python community. This [Scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.mquantiles.html) is created from this [python code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/a8abcfb327fa7bce99becdcbfb2f948c3c1f4cf7/scipy/stats/mstats_basic.py#L1714) using a tool named [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/).

Is anything like that possible for a C# project?

---

Example of XML documentation comments in a .NET project (not mine) https://github.com/haf/NodaTime/blob/master/src/NodaTime/Period.cs#L26

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a period of time expressed in human chronological terms: hours, days,
/// weeks, months and so on. All implementations in Noda Time are immutable, and return fields
/// in descending size order: hours before minutes, for example.
/// </summary>
public sealed class Period : IEnumerable<DurationFieldValue>, IEquatable<Period>
```

---

Edit: The full extent of advice I could find in other questions was 'use [Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.codeplex.com/)'. As far as I can tell from its (ironically limited) documentation, it can only create Windows help files (`.chm`). Is that correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Edit: The full extent of advice I could find in other questions was 'use Sandcastle'. As far as I can tell from its (ironically limited) documentation, it can only create Windows help files (.chm). Is that correct?

No, that's not correct. Sandcastle can build a wide range of output.

However, these days you *really* want [Sandcastle Help-File Builder (SHFB)](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB) which makes things a whole lot better. Still not entirely painless, but pretty good. The documentation for SHFB is generally pretty reasonable, too.

Funny you should give an example of Noda Time - SHFB is precisely what we use to generate our [online API reference](http://nodatime.org/api).

Comment: Brilliant, that's the kind of website I want to make. I'll download SHFB and see how far I can get.

Comment: It worked, but prohibitively slowly. It took one hour to create a website for an 8 MB C# project.

Comment: @ColonelPanic: Check whether you've got MSDN caching turned on. You want it :) Once it's on, it should be *much* faster to do later builds. Or you may be able to turn off MSDN linking entirely, of course.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try [sharpDox](http://sharpdox.de/en). Another free and open source documentation generator.
You are able to create html and chm output and soon word documents.

Here is an example for a [html output](http://sharpdox.de/en/doc/).

P.S.: I am the creator of this tool.

Comment: It appears that sharpDox is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 1):

For a one-click solution, you can also try our [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html).

Comment: Thanks Peter. It worked--and much faster than Sandcastle/SHFB. The output is pretty too. However, I found Visual Studio was significantly slowed by the add-in.

Comment: Thank you for trying VSdocman. If you don't mind, could you please contact us directly at http://www.helixoft.com/contact.html so we can discuss the issue off this forum?