# C# xmldoc to documentation page

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

I've been using Swagger recently for a WebAPI project, and I like the documentation and its inclusion of the XML Documentation I put on my methods. I have various other non-WebAPI project that I'd like to generate documentation for. I know sandcastle exists, and I've used it previously, but it isn't maintained anymore. There is a fork that *is* maintained (the fork doesn't appear to be much of a change over the original). Additionally, it isn't the "prettiest" thing on the planet to use (or what it generates). Previously I used the output and Google promptly down-ranked me for not supporting mobile content.

Are there any other documentation generators that make modern websites that scale nicely on a desktop and mobile devices? Am I just relegated to making the documentation manually?

This is similar to [How to create website from XML documentation comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228111/how-to-create-website-from-xml-documentation-comments), however, that is four years old and as we all know, a lot of changes in technology in 4 years. I'm looking for *current* information.

Comment: Unsure about [Sandcastle](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB) _"not being maintained anymore"_ . Perhaps clone and extend to your needs (and give back to community) :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create website from XML documentation comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228111/how-to-create-website-from-xml-documentation-comments)

Comment: @EdSF, the [original is no longer maintained](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sandcastle). The fork you linked to is actively maintained, but it seems to be sticking to the original output format of the original project. I wasn't a fan of the original tool and the output it generated. I am _always_ happy to contribute back to the community, but I _hate_ reinventing the wheel, hence my question.

Answer (score 2):

DocFX makes it very easy to combine generated and manual documentation

https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/

It was developed by Microsoft for the replacement of the MSDN documentation portal, and made open source.

Comment: Definitely along the lines of what I'm looking for.